# self submit form acces variables javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a site for some peaple of my class and I want them to be able to login. I don't want to make an extra loginpage, so I created this bit of code for my login system, but it doesn't work. I looked al over the internet to find other soloutions, but with no success... I want the person to type in their username and password and I want to store that information in a javascript function, so that I can do a function like tis:

```
function passCheck  () {
    if (pass="johndohpassword1234") // userbname johndoe and passsword password1234 
    {
        document.getElementById('h').innerHTML= "welcome, John!";
    }
```

this is my code:

```html
<?php

$id = $_POST[username] . $_POST[password];

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
  
        var pass=" <?php echo "$id"; ?>";
        window.alert( "welkom, " + pass );

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="h">Login</h1> <br>
    <form action="http://timkast.tk" method="post">
        <b>Username:</b><input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        <b>Password:</b><input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

everything works fine, but the code for `window.alert` does nothing and I dont know why, please can someone explain/fix this?

Comment: Well for one thing it's supposed to be `alert()`, not `allert()`. And it's a method of `window` not `document`.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i fixed it and it still doesn't do what I want it to do

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a `src` for the `script` tag, it ignores the contents of the script tag.

As specified in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src):

> If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write code into a `<script>` tag with reference to external file `<script src="...">`.

You have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">

    var pass=" <?php echo "$id"; ?>";
    window.alert( "welkom, " + pass );

</script>
```

And you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script>

    var pass=" <?php echo "$id"; ?>";
    window.alert( "welkom, " + pass );

</script>
```

Comment: one problem fixed, but when I try to make the checkpass function it doesn't work

Comment: You are not calling the function in nowhere. You must to call the function `onsubmit` event. Your form is submitting to `http://timkast.tk` (`action`  attribute)

Comment: when I do the script thing I get an erroor "unexpected token "<" in index.php" :(

Comment: You are not sharing the correct piece of code. Try to reproduce the problem in a stacksnippet or in https://jsfiddle.net and share with us that snippet.